# Метод простых итераций С++, С#, C

Tags: математика

Помогите с решение нелинейного уравнения. Проблема заключается в том, что необходимо выразить функцию как x=fi(x) - как это вообще делается? 
Функция:
2<sup>x</sup> - 2сos(x)=0

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что математика - оффтопик на ruSO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, например, методом Ньютона... Для вашей функции (которую нужно давать в тексте вопроса!!!) ваша `fi(x)` может иметь вид

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]